# SQLAlchemy with postgresql produces error "Could not locate column in row for column 'attype'"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to a postgresql database.  I do:

```
>>> my_engine = create_engine("postgresql://username@localhost:5432/dbname")
>>> my_metadata = MetaData(bind = my_engine)
```

(There's no password on the database.) These go through without any problems, but then I can't reflect the tables:

```
>>> my_metadata.reflect()
```

and get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'attype'"
```

What is causing this and how do I fix it?  It looks like something on the schema level but I can't figure it out.  I can connect to a MySQL database and reflect the tables without any problems.

EDIT: SqlAlchemy 0.9.2, psql server 9.2.5, psql client 8.4.13, psycopg2 2.5.1

EDIT: With echo=True

```
INFO:root:Creating music_engine postgresql://postgres@localhost/musicbrainz_db
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:select version()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:select current_schema()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:show standard_conforming_strings
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT relname FROM pg_class c WHERE relkind = 'r' AND 'echonest' = (select nspname from pg_namespace n where n.oid = c.re
lnamespace)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
            SELECT c.oid
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE (pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid))
            AND c.relname = %(table_name)s AND c.relkind in ('r','v')

INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'table_name': u'status'}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
            SELECT a.attname,
              pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
              (SELECT pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid)
                FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
               WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum
               AND a.atthasdef)
              AS DEFAULT,
              a.attnotnull, a.attnum, a.attrelid as table_oid
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
            WHERE a.attrelid = %(table_oid)s
            AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
            ORDER BY a.attnum

INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'table_oid': 19271}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
            SELECT t.typname as "name",
               pg_catalog.format_type(t.typbasetype, t.typtypmod) as "attype",
               not t.typnotnull as "nullable",
               t.typdefault as "default",
               pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid) as "visible",
               n.nspname as "schema"
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
               LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
            WHERE t.typtype = 'd'

INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
```

Comment: At a guess, your SQLAlchemy is too old for the PostgreSQL version you're running.  What SQLAlchemy version, psycopg2 version, PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Ah, should have included that to begin with.  Edited to add.

Comment: Hm, ok, so fairly current Pg and SQLAlchemy. The old libpq shouldn't matter much, though it's weird. Can you show the actual query SQLAlchemy is running? PostgreSQL logs, with `log_statement = 'all'`, should do it.

Comment: Is this good?  (echonest is one of the schemas in the db)

Comment: Which of those is causing an error? Your logs don't show the errors. Are all of them failing with an error? Just one?

Comment: here's something suspicious - your postgresql server is 9.2 but your client library is only 8.4?   did you build psycopg2 against the 8.4 client libs?  that's a possible place this is going wrong.  the "attname" column is clearly in the SELECT statement so not sure why that isn't present in cursor.description.  haven't seen that before.

Comment: @CraigRinger: When I run my python script, the error gets printed on stdout on the my_metadata.reflect() line.  The SQL statements go into the logs so I'm not sure how to figure out which one is associated with the error.  The odd thing is that I can run the final query (the only one that even mentions 'attype') in a separate psql client and it's fine.

Comment: @zzzeeek: I didn't build psycopg2 so I'm not sure which libs it uses.  Is there a way I can find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed related to versions, but in Python and psycopg2, not SQLAlchemy or PostgresQL.

I had installed SQLAlchemy in my python2.6 site-packages.  I set my PYTHONPATH appropriately, so I figured it didn't matter whether I used python2.6 or python2.7.  However, it DID matter because SQLAlchemy would always call psycopg2 for python2.6, and the native part of psycopg2 compiled for python2.6 is incompatible with python2.7.